# Saving certificate to keychain with CFDataRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, certificate, keychain

I'm trying to obtain a `CFDataRef` persistent reference for my `SecIdentityRef` identity. However, when using the standard code provided by apple, the function returns 0x0 for `CFDataRef`. The input parameter is not nil, yet somehow it does not work anymore. The code use to work perfectly.

```
CFTypeRef persistent_ref;

CFDataRef persistentRefForIdentity(SecIdentityRef identity)
{
   const void *keys[] = { kSecReturnPersistentRef, kSecValueRef };
   const void *values[] = { kCFBooleanTrue, identity };

   CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 2, NULL, NULL);

   OSStatus status = SecItemAdd(dict, &persistent_ref); // `SecItemAdd` returns 0

   if (dict)
       CFRelease(dict);

   return (CFDataRef)persistent_ref;
}
```

`status` is 0, yet `persistent_ref` still has no value.

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Look's like Listing 2-3 from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13. Have you obtained identity like it's done in Listing 2-1?

Comment: May be problem in `presistent_ref` that it's global variable. May be it's changed in some other method? Make it local.

Comment: Yes I'm obtaining the identity from the PKCS-12 data. When trying to make the variable `persistent_ref` local, it still remains 0x0.

Answer (score 1):

Make the CFTypeRef persistent_ref a local variable. Or make sure you set it to NULL before you call SecItemAdd function. Please see the code below.

```
CFDataRef persistentRefForIdentity (SecIdentityRef identity)
{
  OSStatus status = errSecSuccess;

  CFTypeRef  persistent_ref = NULL;
  const void *keys[] =   { kSecReturnPersistentRef, kSecValueRef };
  const void *values[] = { kCFBooleanTrue,          identity };

  CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 2, NULL, NULL);

  // Delete anything already added
  SecItemDelete(dict);

  //Add the new one
  status = SecItemAdd (dict, &persistent_ref);

  if (status != errSecSuccess)
    return nil;

  if (dict)
      CFRelease(dict);

  return (CFDataRef)persistent_ref;
}
```